# Facebook Page Tab App - Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm building Facebook page tab app. Page is not published, app is in development mode.

I'm using Facebook SDK for PHP 4.0.

When I try to make a request I get **"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."** exception message.

I tried code from FB dev page, several other solutions, but I'm stuck at same point every time.

EDIT:

**Don't forget to grant permission on facebook for app in development.**

Here URL:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

And working version:

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fb['appId'], $fb['secret']);

    $pageHelper = new FacebookPageTabHelper();
    $this->session = $pageHelper->getSession();

    try {
        $this->session->validate();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    try {
        $me = (new FacebookRequest(
            $this->session, 'GET', '/me'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: FacebookSession::newAppSession(); is creating an App Access token. Of course /me will not return the logged in user. Use FacebookPageTabHelper instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried PageTabHelper several attempts back, but I did not have permissions granted for this FB app. :(